# mfc110ud.dll is missing for vc++ project on visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I wrote a vc++ project in vc++ using VS 2012 IDE. Its working well and good in my system.
When I am trying to run on other system (In which he is not having VS2012), we are getting "MFC110ud.dll is missing" error(first pic). I tried to manually place that dll but it is saying illegal usage of mfcud.dll (second pic).

Can some one guide me, how to clear that????

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the **release** version of your program on the other system. It is normal that the debug version won't run on systems where VS2012 os not installed.

Additionally you might need to install the [VS2012 redistributable package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=30679).

Comment: A note on the second error: The OP copied a DLL with the wrong bitness, i.e. either a 64-bit DLL to the SysWOW64 folder, or a 32-bit DLL to the System32 folder on a 64-bit system.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that, if you are running it within Remote Debugging, that the use of the MFC needs to be changed.  Within the project settings (right-click the project from the 'Solution Explorer' panel --> Properties), expand the:

- Configuration Properties
- General

Then, under the 'Project Defaults' in the right panel, select "Use MFC in a Static Library" for the "Use of MFC" property.