# mfc110ud.dll required for Release version of MFC app

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mfc

I have a very simple MFC application built in VS12. When I’m trying to install it on a Surface tablet (Win 8.1) I’m getting an error about mfc110ud.dll being missing. I looked up this dll and it says “MFCDLL Shared Library - Debug Version”. The problem is I’m building my app in Release mode. Why do I still depend on VS?

Comment: Your app could include a library or DLL that is a debug build. The "Depends.exe" tool might show more info about what your app depends on.

Comment: Open a Developer Command Prompt for VS2012 and type `dumpbin /imports:mfc11ud.dll <my application.exe>`. This will tell you which methods are imported, and give you valuable hints towards the root cause. Of course you can also inspect your .vcproj files to see if any of them link against the debug version of MFC by accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the linker /verbose Option to find the module  or library that requires the DLL Version of the MFC.

Answer (score 0):

See this particular post:

[mfc110ud.dll is missing for vc++ project on visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462290/mfc110ud-dll-is-missing-for-vc-project-on-visual-studio-2012/50743738#50743738)

Potentially a duplicate (recompile with "Use of MFC" as "Use MFC in a static Library" when you compile)